# What method in opencv should I use for this?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, template-matching

I have an image that looks like this:

[image: Settlers of Catan board]

This is for the game [Settlers of Catan](http://www.catan.com/).  I want to parse this image to gather 3 pieces of info about each tile.  1. What resource it is 2. What number is associated with it 3. What neighbors it has.  For example, know that the first one is green (forrest) with a 6, the next is wheat with a 5, the next is ore with a 9, and so on... I'm not sure what to use in opencv.  I was thinking templateMatch but sometimes the pieces are with a different orientation (rotated).

[image: Another Settlers of Catan board]

In this board, the spots outlined in black are rotated.

The board will always have a set number of tiles.  Meaning there will always 4 forrests, 4 wheats, 3 ores, etc...

Any direction on what I should do will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Share the samples with **different orientation (rotated)**.

Comment: @BhushanPatil, See edits. Thanks in advance

Comment: 2, 3, 4, 6 & 11 all look the same to me. And 3 looks different in the first image from the second? I don't get it :-(

Comment: @MarkSetchell, sorry for the confusion.  These boards are different instances of the game.  Each time you play, the board is completely different (that's the beauty of the game).  Let me know if you have any other questions